# Counting Letters Between the First and Last - Java

Tags: java

OK, so I'm doing this project that requires that I have the first and last setters of a string appear with the number of letters in between them counted, and output.  I've tried repurposing some reverse a string code I had handy, but I cannot get the output to appear in my IDE.

Can anyone look over my code, and make some suggestions?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String countWord;
    countWord = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
            "Enter the string you wish to have formatted:");
}

static String countMe(String countWord) {
    int count = 1;
    char first = countWord.charAt (0);
    char last = countWord.charAt(-1);
    StringBuilder word = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = countWord.length() - 1; i >= 0; --i)
        if (countWord.charAt(i) != first ) {
            if (countWord.charAt(i) != last) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return countWord + first + count + last;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the "setter of a string"?

Comment: I think you want char last = countWord.charAt(countWord.length - 1);, also why not just use countWord.length - 2 to get the count of chars in the middle?

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to do, and I don't get what you are having trouble with. Could you clarify both please?

Comment: The countWord.charAt(-1) will certainly throw a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: I am trying to take a word or string say "Steven", and have it output S4N the first and last letters of Steven, and the number of letters in the section between.

Answer (score 2):

Just build it using [`charAt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29):

```
return "" + str.charAt(0) + (str.length() - 2) + str.charAt(str.length() - 1);
```

The `""` at the front causes the numeric values that follow to be concatenated as Strings (instead of added arithmetically).

---

A *slightly* more terse alternative is:

```
return countWord.replaceAll("(.).*(.)", "$1" + (str.length() - 2) + "$2")
```

Comment: Where would I implement that?

Comment: Delete all your code for the method and replace it with this single line. You'll need to call it of course and display the string returned.

Answer (score 1):

Once you determined the first and last chars, it is no need for unnecessary conditions. Just try this:

```
static String countMe(String countWord) {

char first = countWord.charAt(0);
char last = countWord.charAt(countWord.length()-1);

int count=0;

for (int i = 1; i < countWord.length()-1; i++)
    {
        count++;
    }
    return first + String.valueOf(count) + last;
    }
```

Or, if it is not mandatory to use for loop, you can make it simple as this

```
static String countMe(String countWord) {
char first = countWord.charAt(0);
char last = countWord.charAt(countWord.length()-1);

int count = countWord.substring(1, countWord.length()-1).length();

return first + String.valueOf(count) + last;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the string.length() method to obtain the total length of the string. Your code would be something like:

```
int totalLength = countWord.length();
int betweenLength = totalLength - 2; // This gives the count of characters between first and last letters
char first = countWord.charAt(0);
char last = countWord.charAt(str.length() - 1);
String answer = first + betweenLength + last;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String countWord;
        countWord = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                "Enter the word you wish to have formatted:");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, countMe(countWord));
    }

    static String countMe(String countWord) {
        int count = 0;
        String first = String.valueOf(countWord.charAt(0));
        String last = String.valueOf(countWord.charAt(countWord.length() - 1));
        for(int i = 1; i < countWord.length() - 1; i++) {
            if (String.valueOf(countWord.charAt(i)) != first ) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return first + count + last;
    }
}
```